# Is there a word for my relation to ex-wife's child?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

If I marry a woman and she has a child, I am a step parent.  But what if the sequence is reversed? For example, suppose I am married to a woman, get divorced and she subsequently has a child by someone else.  Is there any word in the English language to describe what my relationship (if any) is to this child?

This is my situation; I'm close to this child and always at a loss to describe our situation as other than family friend. Can anyone offer another suggestion?

Comment: The child of your ex-wife by another man? With whom you share not legal or blood tie? There is no word for that in my American dialect.

Comment: Like "selfie" I suppose is a new word just approved last year by Oxford , I guess you could recommend some word for such a relationship to Oxford .... Situations and circumstances are the cause of words..

Comment: I would go with "a pal", or "my favorite youngster".

Comment: If really pressed to describe your rapport, I'd say something like: "I used to be married to his mother" and then "The kid decided to adopt me as his uncle/grown-up friend" or something similar. (Hope this helps)

Comment: My cousin, who is in such a relationship, is called *Uncle* by his ex-wife's child. They also share a child so his daughter is half sister to his *neo-nephew*. Informal and not fitting common definitions.

Comment: I wish there was a word. In my situation, the son of my former husband and his current wife is half brother to my three children AND I am very close to him. I call myself his mom-wanna-be since there is no word. “Ex-husband’s son” sounds so non-caring, so non-family. The “half-brother to my kids” even more so. Neither terminology announces my relationship to him, where I can easily say that I love him like my own. It would seem that in this day and age that a good word for this relationship would be created.

Answer (score 3):

"My ex-wife's child" is the proper description for your blood-or-marriage relationship with this child.

If you are back with your ex, you can call the child your step-child. If you adopt them, they are now your son/daughter.

Unlike "Significant other" (SO), there is no terminology yet to *name* this particular relationship that you can use and expect to be understood exactly.

Having said that, whose business is it that you would need to explain yourself so precisely? If he loves you like a father, and you love him like a son, and the mother goes along with this, describe him as your step-son. If someone questions you, politely steer the conversation the way you want it to go. "As I was saying, it was a great game. Have you been to any games lately?"